# Lazy load of spring beans

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, lazy-loading, spring-cloud-config-server

Is that possible to use the **spring.main.lazy-initialization** property with config server?

I have spring-boot microservices running on k8s. The properties are loaded from the config server based on the env.

I just can't make it work. To enable lazy init with the property.
The only way it worked, was setting true on the SpringApplication flag before invoking the method run.

Tested on spring-boot 2.3.12.RELEASE

Comment: try (in): `bootstrap.properties`(?;)

Comment: No. As that property is used very early i the process afaik. Which basically already pre-configures the context and then additional sources are loaded.